# Tax not applied to all products

Tags: products, tax, tax-class

I have a strange problem and I hope its me who is doing something wrong.

When I see an order in admin, I see that tax is not applied to all products. It is 0 for many. I checked each such product in catalog->products and found that they have same tax class assigned as the product on which tax is calculated.

Please tell me where I should look for this. The information regarding tax setting is this:

[image]

Comment: I think, it's because of you having `tax calculation based on 'shipping address'`. Is shipping address same for all items?

Comment: Yes, all products are in same order, hence same shipping address

Comment: So, what does your tax rules look like? Do you use many rules, zones, countries, different rates? Did you reindex your data? Did it work before (is it a new shop or an existing one)? Any 3rd party extensions around catalog or sales installed? If so, try to disable them and check again. There are a lot of possibilities...